# How can I schedule a daily task with automator on os x 10.6?

Tags: macos, scheduled-tasks, automator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [User friendly way to schedule jobs in Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/44849/user-friendly-way-to-schedule-jobs-in-mac-os-x)

I have a script that I want to run once every day.  I know I can do this with cron but it also seems there should be a way to do it through the UI.

How can I schedule the script to run on a daily basis on OS X 10.6?

G-Man

Comment: dupe.  http://superuser.com/questions/44849

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could schedule an event in iCal and set an alarm to "Run Script"

Comment: I don't see a way for it to run daily tho

Comment: +1 Although I find it odd coming from Windows, this is the "real" method for scheduling tasks through the Mac OS X GUI.

Comment: @geoggreyf67 - set the event to repeat

Comment: @Stephen: I wouldn't say it's the "real" method, but it's _one_ method. An alternative is to use Launch Daemons (or Agents if the script needs to use the GUI). http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Articles/LaunchOnDemandDaemons.html , but that is a more technical solution that some people might find a bit daunting.